# Will the memory reference of the Node object be same in both cases?

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
```

Consider this as the Node(DLL) Structure, I have following two implementations of a function that I care to use:

```
1.
def put(self, key, value):
       """
       :type key: int
       :type value: int
       :rtype: void
       """
       if key not in self.hashmap:
           self.hashmap[key] = Node(key, value)
           self.add(hashmap[key])


2.
self.hashmap[key] = Node(key, value)
             self.add(Node(key, value))
```

In both the cases, I am trying to add the Node value to the class structure. In (1), I am quite sure that the value of `hashmap[key]` which is `Node(key, value)` will be added.

My hunch tells me that in case (2), a new object will be created and added rather than the same object that's created in line `self.hashmap[key] = Node(key, value)`.

Is my hunch correct? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, you are explicitly creating a new Node.

Comment: so the memory reference to both will be different in case 2?

Comment: That's a logical consequence of creating a new object, yes. You can't store two different objects in the same memory, can you?

Comment: Yes, it will, unless you somehow implement `__new__` or a metaclass which intercepts object creation and returns a cached object, like a singleton class, but normally, calling a constructor like `Node` will create a *new object* by default.